# Using python for loop inside brackets

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

Actually I encounter one code today which is shown below:

```
def solution(ar,n):
    d={i: ar[i] for i in range(n)}
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1,n-1):
            if(ar[i]+ar[j]) in d.values():
                return "Yes"
        return "No"
```

So in this function I am not able to understand this line of code

```
d= {i : ar[i] for i in range(n)}
```

Can someone please explain me what this code will do and about this syntax?

Comment: This is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/); an expression to create a dictionary by iterating over a collection of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it is possible to simplify for-loops:

```
l = []
for i in range(3):
    l.append(i)
```

can be simplified with

```
l = [i for i in range(3)]
```

The same rules can also be applied to dictionaries. The given line is defining a dictionary (d) with the key i and the value ar[i] for every element. It is a short version for the following code.

```
d = dict()
for i in range(n):
    d[i] = ar[i]
```